# sending System.out over socket

Tags: java, sockets, system.out

How do I send output from System.out to socket e.g. PrintWriter?

I need to send whatever appears on the console output (both std and err) to PrintWriter, thus a socket.

Thank you.

Comment: have you considered using a logger?

Comment: Some ideas: https://blogs.oracle.com/nickstephen/entry/java_redirecting_system_out_and

Comment: I know there is a System.setOut() method, but how to pass PrintWriter instead of a PritStream?

Answer (score 4):

May be you can try like this:

```
OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream(); // for example
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(os);
System.setOut(ps);
```

Comment: I would have to edit plenty of code to use PrintStream, at he moment I'm using PrintWriter. Any ideas on how to System.setOut() to PrintWriter? If it isn't doable then I'll have to switch to PrintStream. Thanks

Comment: you can do like this:PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(System.out, true);

Comment: OK. But how Am I using it later?!? My PrintWriter already point to the socket: PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(m_clientSocket.getOutputStream())); and then I can do e.g. out.println();  Wouldn't your out print to console instead of socket?!? Correct me if I'm wrong I have to try this out.

Comment: Hence forth if you say System.out.println("hello"), will be redirected to socket

Comment: I don't seem to understand it ;( Where should I declare the out variable to use the socket? What order and how when I can't have duplicate declarations.

Comment: PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(m_clientSocket.getOutputStream())); and PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(System.out, true);

Comment: PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(m_clientSocket.getOutputStream()));
 OutputStream os = new WriterOutputStream(out);
 PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(os);
 System.setOut(ps);

Comment: It worked fine after importing org.apache.commons.io... Thank you very much. After System.out.println(); There is a need for System.out.flush();

Answer (score 0):

Well, you *can*, but please be more specific about your requirements. If you want to send logging messages, you'll better use some logging framework like [logback](/questions/tagged/logback) where you can switch from `ConsoleAppender` to `SocketAppender` immediately.

You can also replace `System.out` with `System.setOut()` and redirect output to some other target.

If you want to redirect the whole output of some application, you can try some bash/`nc` workaround as well:

```
$ java -jar your_app.jar | nc some_server
```

Comment: Going for logging framework seems to be a good idea and should help me  address other issues. Thank you.